# Div with text after don't align

Tags: jquery, html, css

I need to create legend below jQuery datepicker. I am using divs with styling to represent different date markings I am using for highlighting days. Legends below dont align nicely somehow.

Here is my code: http://jsfiddle.net/kaktusas2598/Lh3Lxa0g/1/[1](http://jsfiddle.net/kaktusas2598/Lh3Lxa0g/1/)

```
<div class="row">
    <div class="span3">
        <h4>Select day</h4>
    </div>
    <div class="span7">
        <h4 id="hour"></h4>
    </div>
</div>
<div class="row">
    <div class="span3">
         <div id="datepicker"></div>
        <ul>
        <!---->
            <li>
            <div class="ui-state-default" style="float: left; width: 20px; height: 20px; margin: 5px;   
        border-color:red;background: red;color: white;">5</div>- More than 10 reservations.</li>
            <li>
            <div class="ui-state-default" style="float: left; width: 20px; height: 20px; margin: 5px;   
            border-color:green;background: green;color: white;">5</div>- Less than 10 reservations.</li>
            <li>
            <div class="ui-state-default" style="float: left; width: 20px; height: 20px; margin: 5px;">5</div>- No reservations.</li>
    </ul>
</div>
<!---->
<div class="span7" id="hours"></div>
```

Comment: Dont know why, but when I added `position:absolute;` to the second div it works fine =) (However, if I add it to all three divs, they act up)

Comment: why unnecessary you adding div inside the li?

Comment: IDK, I need to create legend icons with div, or something

Comment: you could use span and remove the `float:left` check this link. http://jsbin.com/xixebapa/1/edit

Comment: @JohanHjalmarsson http://jsfiddle.net/kaktusas2598/Lh3Lxa0g/5/ Thank uou, your solution works best.

Comment: @kaktusas2598 have you checked DEMO link? Is that solution won't work for you?

Comment: @KheemaPandey Thank you, it also work, dunno which one is better :)

Comment: well @kaktusas2598 when you used `position absolute` in any element its goes out of the normal flow. also check using shrinking the browser which one is still better then decided.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should use display:inline-table and should remove float. Avoid float as far as you can  since most of the time it creates confusion:

```
<li>
                <div class="ui-state-default" style="display:inline-table; width: 20px; height: 20px; margin: 5px;   
            border-color:red;background: red;color: white;">5</div>- More than 10 reservations.</li>
```

fiddle:

> http://jsfiddle.net/learner420/Lh3Lxa0g/7/

Answer (score 1):

Add clear:left style on your floated legend divs

Comment: http://jsfiddle.net/kaktusas2598/Lh3Lxa0g/4/ It's still not quite right, something wrokn with text height.

Answer (score 1):

As you are using  `ul` to represent the items in each line then you no need to add `float:left` and create an extra `div` in each `li` anymore.

just simply you can use `span` to highlight the exact part.
by just removing the `float:left` from your code and replace `div` with `span`

just used this small CSS. Have a look at **[DEMO](http://jsbin.com/xixebapa/1/edit)**.

```
li, span{padding:5px;}
```

Comment: try to use prev and next buttons on datePicker, doesnt look good

Comment: In my code its not working because I am  using the jquery UI version `1.9.2` and in your version its working because you using version `1.10.3`. Lets stick with your jquery version and arrow will work fine.

Comment: Sry, still doesnt works, looks like each cell of datepicker have its padding extended.

Comment: hey got it.. `li, span{padding:5px;}` replace this with `.span3 li, .span3 li span{padding:5px;}`

Comment: span3 is bootstrap class, is it ok to change it? I don't want to overwrite it.

Comment: you are not doing anything with class `.span3` what I am doing here just make a strong specificity Rule here for `span` element so other `span` won't get affected.

Comment: It works, thank u for your efforts. Approach above with `display:inline-table;` also works. So I will test both ways, and pick better one.

Answer (score 0):

I've removed the inline styles which were all the same and added them in CSS,

The problem was the margins on the `div` which was thus `overflowing` and making them `div`s out of place.  You can also play with adding `overflow:none` onto the `li` which has a similar effect.

```
li div {
    float:left;
    width:20px;
    height:20px;
}

ul li {
    padding:1px;
    margin:5px;
}
```

Demo: http://jsfiddle.net/robschmuecker/8zfdmjay/